log4net not logging/creating log file
I am trying to use, for logging for a c# console app that I created. It doesn't seem to work for some reason , or I am not sure what I missed. Any help ?
log4net.config

Program.cs
using System;

  [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]

  public class SearchCardsML
   {

      private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = 
                        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
          (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          logger.Info("Started....");
      }
 
    }


Project Tree


Check if your file path is correct and also your DatePattern is ok.

It looks like you are trying to use the normal file appender as a rolling file appender. Search for 'rolling' here to see an example: https://blog.elmah.io/log4net-tutorial-the-complete-guide-for-beginners-and-pros/

I forgot to use 'Copy Always' settings, i really dont understand how this impacted from creating logs , but it works now


Two things that I noticed:

I'm pretty sure the configuration of file@value doesn't need to have backslashes escaped, i.e. you could write value="C:\app\log-".
Does the user account that executes your program have Write permissions on the c:\app directory? If not, nothing can be written. (By the way, you might want to have a separate log directory so that you don't need to grant Write permissions to the c:\app directory, which could be a security issue).

